# In Xcode view-based Interface Builder, Can you use the makeKeyAndOrderFront with a simple UIWindow?

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, uiwindow

If not what's the difference between NSWindow and UIWindow?

And how exactly would I implement this makeKeyandOrderFront function?

Here's all the code I have so far.

```
//
//  DisappearanceViewController.h
//  Disappearance
//
//  Created by Angelo Rivera on 2/24/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Cal State Uniuversity Channel Islands. All rights reserved.
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface DisappearanceViewController : UIViewController 
{
IBOutlet UIImageView *view1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;    

}

-(IBAction)toggleLabel: (id)sender;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *view1;

@end



//
//  DisappearanceViewController.m
//  Disappearance
//
//  Created by Andrew Rivera on 2/24/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Cal State Uniuversity Channel Islands. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DisappearanceViewController.h"

@implementation DisappearanceViewController

int i = 0;

-(IBAction)toggleLabel:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;

    if (i ==0)
    {
    label.text = @"Hello World";
    }

    else {
            label.text = @"lmao";
    }
    i++;

}
/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What does that code have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

The [UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) class does not have a method called `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`; it *does* have a method called [`makeKeyAndVisible`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-BABBEBEA) which seems to be the closest thing on iOS. A search of the documentation would've answered that, if that's all you're asking.